# How are *Mortarboard*, *Epic* and *Legendary* badges earned on meta?

Tags: discussion, badges, meta-reputation

I saw that the *[Mortarboard](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard)*, *[Epic](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic)* and *[Legendary](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary)* badges are also there available on the meta site and *[Normal Human](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic?userid=147263)* has been the sole winner of the *Epic* badge.

[image]

But I knew that there is no reputation earned on meta. Then how are these badges earned?

Comment: It's probably just calculating reputation as normal (but with no visible effect) and awarding it based off of that - meta has all the information needed to assign users a reputation, it just doesn't.

Comment: I guess that the correct question should have been: why are these badges offered on *meta* sites? No, let me correct that: why are there badges?

Comment: @AlexM. Because [gamification](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/). See also: [Why are badges motivating?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61729), [Does SE have too many badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189444#189445)

Answer (score 17):

There is no *visible* reputation earned on per-site metas. But since their code has a lot in common with the main site code, some processes function in essentially the same way. So, the system still tallies up the points "received" from upvotes, etc, and awards badges accordingly.

See: [Should I really have been awarded mortarboard on a Per-site meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78603/should-i-really-have-been-awarded-mortarboard-on-a-per-site-meta)